# How do I create a variable for each character of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im making the hangman game in python 3.11 and I'm trying to make a variable for each character of the word chosen, here is the code:

```
import os

word = "audio"
    
for i in range(len(word)):
    word[i] = False

while True:
    guessed = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if getattr(sys.modules[__name__], word[i]):
            guessed += word[i]
        else:
            guessed += "_"
    print(guessed)
```

Though when I try do this i get the error.

```
    word\[i\] = False
         ^^^
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment.
```

I have even thought to do this.

```
for i in range(len(word)):
    eval(f"{word[i]} = False")
```

What eval does if you don't know it runs the string input as code so it should work but now, I get another error, this is it

```
    a = False
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which doesn't seem right as that looks like correct syntax?

Anyone have any answers on how I could do this?

It should make a variable with the name being each of character of the chosen word
e.g.
word = "audio"

```
a = False
u = False
d = False
i = False
o = False
```

but have it so that when the word changes the variable names also change in accordance with the word.

Comment: Don't do it, use a dictionary.

Comment: i think you should apply dictionary.. your word is `str` format and in python it is `immutable`